# How do I create frames/tabs in C# Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I know there is a tab control in the Windows Forms Builder. The thing is, I want to create something a little nicer. It seems like there's not many stylistic changes you can make to that control in specific, and it looks kind of ugly.

Is there either a way of creating a custom tab control, or using buttons to switch from pane to pane?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TabControl` has a DrawMode property.  Change it to:

```
tabControl1.DrawMode = OwnerDrawFixed;
```

and then wire up the `DrawItem` event.  Of course, then you have to draw the rest yourself to your own liking.

If you are looking for something more, DevExpress has free WinForm controls, which includes their `TabControl` version.

Comment: I'm using DevExpress's free tab control. Its working really well. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

To change the Tabcontrol to use button to switch the tab pages, use below code:

```
 this.tabControl1.Appearance = TabAppearance.Buttons;
```

Comment: How can I further style those buttons?

Comment: WPF might be a good choice, provided that you are not constrained in WinForm.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [DockPanel Suite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite/) for this sort of thing before and just not used all the tool window stuff.